# Want to know if i'm doing these probability questions correctly

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

1. How many rolls of a perfect (fair) die are needed so that the probability of 5 appearing at least once is at least 9/10?

P(A) = P(5 occurs atleast once) = 1/6

P($A^c$) = P(Everything except 5 occurs atleast once) = 5/6

If the dice is rolled twice, the complement gives us  (5/6)*(5/6) => $(5/6)^2$ so if we roll the dice N times our complement would be $(5/6)^n $

Thus for $1-(5/6)^n$ to be atleast 9/10 the dice must be rolled 13 times. 
$1-(5/6)^{13}$ = .9065

2. Urn A has 7 black and 7 white marbles, and Urn B has 10 black and 3 white marbles. You randomly select one marble from each urn. What is the probability that you end up with two black marbles?

P(A) = P(1 black from urn A) = 7/14

P(B) = P(1 black from urn B) = 10/13

P(A)*P(B) =  .3846

3. A perfect die is rolled 4 times. If it is known that a 3 appeared at least once, what is the probability that it appeared exactly twice?

$_nC_k*p^kq^{n−k}$ can be used for this problem

n = 4 rolls

p = 1/6 (3 appears once)

q = 5/6 (complement of p)

k = 2 (how many times we want 3 to appear)

$_4C_2*(1/6)^2(5/6)^{4−2} = .1157$

4. The completion of a highway construction project may be delayed because of a storm.The probabilities are .60 that there will be a storm, .85 that the construction job will be completed on time if there is no storm, and .35 that the construction job will be completed on time if there is a storm. What is the probability that the construction job will be completed on time?

$P(A|B) = P(A ∩ B )/P(B)$

$        = .35/.85 = .41 $

Comment: "P(A) = P(5 occurs atleast once) = 1/6 "  What exactly do you mean by this?  Do you mean that if you roll a dice exactly once it will have a probability of 1/6 of being a 5?  If so, this is correct but that is not what you wrote.  Or did you mean that no matter how many times you roll a die the probabiltiy of 5 occuring at least once is 1/6?  If so, that is what you wrote but it is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Your answer and reasoning to 1) is absolutely correct but your explanation and wording ("Probability 5 occurs at least once" =1/6) and ("everything except 5 occurs at least once" = 5/6) is messy and sloppy to the point that I would simply call it "wrong".

Comment: @fleablood Yes I meant " if you roll a dice exactly once it will have a probability of 1/6 of being a 5" I'll make sure to clarify that on the hw

Comment: @Sammy A clear and concise presentation of your ideas to the reader is as at least as important as getting the numbers right.  If nothing else, you may be the reader when revising for an exam, and you don't want to be puzzling out "what the heck did was mean by that?"   You certainly don't want an exam marker to be doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 looks correct (you got the right idea, at least ... the wording and execution can be improved ... e.g. show that with 12 rolls you are still below $0.9$)

2 is correct ...

3 looks incorrect (you need to use a conditional probability here) ...

and 4 is certainly incorrect:

For 4:

$A$:storm

$B$: project completed

$$P(B) = P(B|A)\cdot P(A) + P(B|A^C)\cdot P(A^C)= 0.35\cdot 0.6+0.85\cdot0.4=0.55$$

For 3:  Think back to problem 1: what is the chance $P(\ge 1)$ of getting at least one 3 in 4 rolls?  Now calculate the chance $P(2)$ of getting exactly two 3's, and divide that by $p$ to get your answer, since:

$$P(2)= P(2 \cap \ge 1)= P(2|\ge 1)\cdot P(\ge 1)$$

and so:

$$P(2|\ge 1)=\frac{P(2)}{P(\ge 1)}$$

Comment: so for P(> 1) would it be (1/6)^4? if so to calculate P(2) would it be (2/6)^4?

Comment: @Sammy No. Getting at least one 3is 1 minus not getting any 3's, so $P(\ge 1)= 1-(5/6)^4$. And to get exactly 2 3's you use that formula you indicated: ${4 \choose 2}\cdot \frac{1}{6}^2 \cdot \frac{5}{6}^2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problems 1 and 2 look fine (assuming you mean *exactly* once instead of at least).

For problem 3, you're looking for the probability that you get exactly two 3's, **conditioned** on the fact that you get at least one. Does that help?

For problem 4, you say that you're solving for $P(A | B)$, which doesn't make sense here (I'm not sure what your events are as they don't match up with the probabilities in the problem). Are you familiar at all with the law of total probability?